# Offset Div From Grid

Tags: javascript, html, grid

[image]

Above you will find a sketch of what I am trying to achieve. I am working in a 12 column layout. I want the div .row-2 to max out to 10 columns on the right but go all the way to the edge of .main-container on the left.

Below is what I have to work with but keep getting errors.

```js
$('.main-container').once('.row-2').each(function () {
        $(window).on('resize', function () {
          $('.row-2').each(function () {
            self.align($(this));
          });
        });
      });

      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.row-2', context).once('.row-2').each(function () {
          self.align($(this));
        });
      });

    align: function ($element) {
      $element.css({
        marginLeft: ''
      });
      var maxWidth = $element.width();
      $element.css({
        marginLeft: 'auto'
      });
      $('.row-2', $element).each(function () {
        $(this).css({
          maxWidth: maxWidth,
          marginLeft: 'auto'
        });
      });
      var offset = $element.offset();
      // Use #focus element as wrapping element
      offset.left = offset.left - $('.main-container').offset().left;
      $element.css({
        marginLeft: (offset.left * -1) + 'px'
      });

  };
```

```css
.main-container {
  max-width:1680px;
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#cccccc;
 }
.row-1, .row-2, .row-3 {
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="row-1"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh man. Do yourself a favor and get [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)! You can do offsets [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).

Comment: @StephanGenyk I am using Foundation 6. I am trying to offset the div the the edge of the viewport.

Comment: @StephanGenyk even if I were not to use the .columns class so that .row would go full width it wouldn't stay in line with .row-1 and .row-2 when you resize the browser

Comment: Here is my suggestion. .row-1 and .row-3 should be wrapped with a class with styling that includes max-width:1680px  and margin: 0 auto;. .row-2 should be wrapped with a different class with styling of width: 100%

Comment: @StephanGenyk I want row-1 and .row-3 to stay in my .container though. Certainly I could make .row-2 100% width but how do you stop it in the grid?

Comment: @StephanGenyk please take a look at the concept before making a suggestion https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxzm4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
Here, working example please check below link.

I have set .row-2 in same container but take different css for .row-2 and .row-1 & .row-3

and .row-2 take 10 columna same you need please check it  

https://jsfiddle.net/DineshV/frp1Luzo/
```

[Here is image with center same as you said. you know showed center because of you have nor resize window  ][Check this img]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbhlK.png

Comment: that doesn't keep the left side of .row-2 all the way left and the right side maxed out. I am almost 100% positive this is not achievable just through CSS.

Comment: Check my above comments and screenshot.